# RBAC For phoenix API on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, phoenix-framework, azure-rbac

So I have made an API using phoenix framework. But I have to make Role Based Access Control on Microsft Azure for my API calls example: read access, update access or create access. I am not able to find any blog or resource regarding that if anyone has any idea how to proceed? That would be very helpful.

Also, I don’t want to make a new context in the app for the user and make a database for user and access role.
I want to try Azure RBAC.

PS: Tried Microsoft Azure Documentation but they are not very helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use OpenID within your application and add the roles.

These two guides are both good and should be useful for what you are trying to achieve:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles/README.md

Looks like someone has written a [blog post](https://docs.druva.com/Knowledge_Base/Phoenix/How_to/How_to_configure_SSO_for_Phoenix_using_the_IDP_Azure_AD) on how to assign users and configure SSO for Phoenix using Azure AD. By the looks of it you should probably be able to do this and then follow the usual RBAC configurations using the Azure documentation.

There does not appear to be an official guide for this as of yet but you can request it through User Voice. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback